# Having trouble getting Text to show up in my Python Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I've been trying to figure out how to output two metrics to a chart I'm trying to display. I looked around on here and found that the way to do this was via the `plt.text`

I've tried about 80 different variations and I still can't get it to ouput.

This is my latest code:

```
mae = metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test,y_pred)
mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
y_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime(test_index))
y_pred = y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred), )
y_test = y_test.reshape(len(y_test), )
y_df['y_pred'] = y_pred
y_df['y_test'] = y_test
y_df.plot(title='{}'.format(gsc.best_estimator_))
plt.text(.5, .5, 'MAE:{}\nMSE:{}'.format(mae, mse))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show(block=False)
print('end')
plt.show()
```

My chart will print - but no text. I've tried switching from the `pandas` `matplotlib` wrapper and plotting directly with `plt.plot` but still couldn't get it to run. Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
I've tried to go away from using the pandas wrapper to plot again. Now i'm getting:

[image]

```
mae = metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test,y_pred)
mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
y_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime(test_index))
y_pred = y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred), )
y_test = y_test.reshape(len(y_test), )
y_df['y_pred'] = y_pred
y_df['y_test'] = y_test
line1 = Line2D(test_index, y_pred,color="goldenrod")
line2 = Line2D(test_index, y_test, color="dodgerblue")
#y_df.plot(title='{}'.format(gsc.best_estimator_))
plt.text(.5, .5, 'MAE:{}\nMSE:{}'.format(mae, mse))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show(block=False)
print('end')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem is likely the coordinates of the text. We don't know your dataframe (please consider [mcve]), but most likely `(.5, .5)` is simply way outside the data limits of the plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What if i just want to put it in a legend? Would that be better practice? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why but your code works on my laptop with matplotlib 3.1.0. Maybe you could consider reinstalling matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mae, mse = 1, 1
plt.plot()  # in your case : plt.plot(test_index, y_pred,color="goldenrod")
plt.text(.5, .5, 'MAE:{}\nMSE:{}'.format(mae, mse))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show(block=False)
plt.show()
```

**Regarding the Edit:**
creating Line2D objects like that will not link anything to the actual plot. You can either directly use

```
plt.plot(test_index, y_pred,color="goldenrod") 
plt.plot(test_index, y_test, color="dodgerblue")
plt.show()
```

or

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1 = Line2D(test_index, y_pred,color="goldenrod")
line2 = Line2D(test_index, y_test, color="dodgerblue")
ax.add_line(line1)
ax.add_line(line2)
plt.show()
```

**Adding text with AnchoredText** outside frame

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
at = AnchoredText("My Text",
                   loc='lower left', frameon=True,
                   bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.),
                   bbox_transform=ax.transAxes  # or plt.gca().transAxes
                   )
plt.gca().add_artist(at)
```

play with `bbox_to_anchor` for position.

Comment: do you mind taking a look at the edit i just posted?

Comment: creating Line2D objects like that will not link anything to the actual plot.
Why not use plt.plot(test_index, y_pred,color="goldenrod")

Comment: The figure never shows up when I try that. I'm wondering if maybe it's because y_pred is an array of shape (15567,)?

Comment: weird, can you try using the Line2D as mentionned in my edit ?

Comment: got this error:matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['10/20/2016 1:00', '10/20/2016 1:30',

Comment: The error is pretty clear: Looks like you have some timestamps strings inside your array. Matplotlib cannot work with such data. If you want to plot timestamps, convert the strings to datetime.datetime objects beforehand.

Comment: i dont have an ax anywhere for ax.transAxes. is that plt.gca().transAxes?

Comment: yes, or use ax from plt.subplots() with the Line2D method

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`AnchoredText`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText) to put some text in a corner of the axes.

```
at = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText("My Text", loc='upper right', frameon=True)
plt.gca().add_artist(at)
```

Comment: there it is! my final question would be is there a way to get it to be just outside the plot area instead of on the plot?

Comment: Mhh, apparently the system has duplicated my answer :) Anyways, you can use the `bbox_to_anchor` argument to put the text outside the axes. This works the same as  for a legend so I would point you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132).